# Action App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@search not defined

Tags: laravel-8

What is the problem?This is Laravel 8.

**index.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'FrontendController@search','method'=> 'GET']) !!}
```

**FrontendController**

```
    public function search(Request $request){
          $brand = DB::table('products')->select('brand_name')->distinct()->get()->pluck('brand_name')->sort();
    
          $pro = POST::query();
    
          if($request->filled('brand_name')){
            $pro->where('brand_name',$request->brand_name);
          }
    
          return view('frontend.products.index',[
            'brand'=>$brand,
            'products'=>$pro->get(),
          ]);
       }
```

Comment: check if the given names are right, Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am creating a product filter dropdown for a e commerce site.But i can't find the problem.all names are correct.@Nemoko

Comment: Maybe run `composer dumpautoload`, see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('set your url'),'method'=> 'GET']) !!}
```

`FrontendController@search` this type is not probably used in laravel 8. it is used in lower version of laravel